# Combine DataFrames on Different DateTime Indices

Tags: python, pandas

How can I join two DataFrames that both have datetime indices if is indexed by day and the other by minute? They look like

```
2007-04-02 07:00:00 756.00  756.00  756.00  756.00
2007-04-02 07:01:00 756.00  756.00  756.00  756.00
2007-04-02 07:02:00 756.00  756.00  756.00  756.00
2007-04-02 07:03:00 756.00  756.00  756.00  756.00
2007-04-02 07:04:00 756.00  756.00  756.00  756.00
```

and

```
2020-06-22  5337.0  5376.0  5321.0  5355.0
2020-06-23  5391.0  5399.0  5341.0  5353.0  
2020-06-24  5348.0  5357.0  5332.0  5350.0
2020-06-29  5418.0  5438.0  5352.0  5385.0  
2020-06-30  5451.0  5815.0  5414.0  5643.0
```

respectively. I want to join them such that each row in the daily data is next to the corresponding row of the minute data on the same day, at 3:00 AM.

Comment: What should the join look like? You can use `pd.merge_asof` which allow you to merge on tolerance values (which can be timedeltas).